# How does the arithmetic of redefined symbols work?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

C++ allows programmers to redefine symbols in the fashion of

```
#define A 0
```

but the way these redefined symbols behave when used in the context of each other and with arithmetic is unusual, due to the fact that these values are treated as strings, not literals.

I'm confused on the logic that this arithmetic uses, and was hoping to get an explanation of how it works. I've done multiple tests trying to understand how it works by using different values, but it's still confusing me.

example 1:

```
#define A 0
#define B A+1
#define C 1-B

cout << C;
```

example 2:

```
#define ALPHA 2-1
#define BETA ALPHA * 2

cout << BETA;
```

example 1: expected output is 0, actual output is 2
example 2: expected output is 2, actual output is 0

can anyone explain how exactly this works?

Comment: These are examples of "c preprocessor" macros, not enumerated types (which would involved the keyword `enum`).

Comment: Be warned, there is danger in the use of `#define`. `#define A 0` means that all `A`s in the program will be replaced with 0. The process is utterly mindless, so `A` will be replaced whether or not the substitution makes any sense. That means `class A`  will become `class 0` and because all you see in the code is `class A`, the error messages produced by the compiler can appear to be completely insane like *Expected identifier before numeric constant* Wiith an arrow pointing at the `A` in `class A`

Comment: That said, compilers have gotten a lot better at trying to explain what happened and today you may get something that is only partly insane: https://ideone.com/nB2Co6

Comment: Perhaps it is worth saying that the preprocessor was a hack that supported things otherwise hard to do back in the misty past. Even c has moved on quite a bit since then and c++ offeres *many* features that can (and mostly *should*) replace things we used to do with pre-processor hacks.

Answer (score 3):

Macros are text replacement. Following lines show how the text gets replaced by the pre-processor step by step:

```
cout << C;
cout << 1-B;
cout << 1-A+1;
cout << 1-0+1;

cout << BETA;
cout << ALPHA * 2;
cout << 2-1 * 2;
```

Comment: I like the step-by-step explanation +1

Answer (score 2):

These macros are simply replaced inline with whatever you defined them to be. Thus:

```
#define A 0
#define B A+1
#define C 1-B

cout << C;
```

becomes:

```
cout << 1-0+1;
```

and

```
#define ALPHA 2-1
#define BETA ALPHA * 2

cout << BETA;
```

becomes:

```
cout << 2-1 * 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#define` preprocessor macro supports *textual substitution*. Your two examples get reduced to a single line of c++ code each:

```
cout << 1-0-1;
```

and

```
cout << 2-1 * 2;
```

and the ourput you are getting is exactly what you should expected (keeping in mind that c++ put the precedence of `*` above that of `+` and evaluates equal precedence strings left-to-right.).